# Change height of single char inside a text in html/css

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment, centering

I'm using an Unicode symbol ([U+25C0](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25C0)) to make a "left arrow" on a button, but the symbol itself is shifted down a bit. I couldn't find a way to center it, I tried margins, padding and line-height with no success.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: My text]

And the simple code:

```css
h2 {
  font-family: Oswald;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald">

<h2>
  <span style="font-size: 70%">&#9664</span>
  &nbsp;Return
</h2>
```

I just need to vertically center the symbol, if anyone could help me :)

Comment: h2 {display: flex; align-items: center;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your CSS to center it vertically:

```css
h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

if you want to align it horizontally as well use `justify-content: center;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it because of style="font-size: 70%". When I remove it, it looks fine. try to remove it or move it to another place outside the span element